# split NSString given a number of characters in objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

I have two strings that are taken as input from a textfield in my application. I know that they are both 4 characters in length.

Is there some way I can "halve" those strings, and create two strings per original string that have two characters each?

Comment: Is developer.apple.com down?

Comment: Before asking such questions, scan the reference docs first. A quick glance at the docs for `NSString` would have revealed plenty of useful methods for this. The docs are right in the Xcode Organizer window.

Comment: Have to agree with @rmaddy. If you're new to iOS/Objective-C you should spend some time getting to know NSString, NSArray, NSDictionary, etc. as the time you spend up front will pay significant dividends.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sure.  NSString has the very useful methods ["`substringToIndex:`"](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/substringToIndex%3a) and ["`substringFromIndex:`"](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/substringFromIndex%3a).  The magic number (index) here appears to be 2.

Comment: Just be sure to validate the length of the original string first.

Answer (score 2):

A simple approach would be to use the NSString `substringWithRange:` method to obtain each of the pairs of characters you require.

For example:

```
NSString *sourceString = @"ABCD";

assert([sourceString length] == 4);    // Handle error conditions here.

NSString *firstSection = [sourceString substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0,2)];
NSString *secondSection = [sourceString substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(2,2)];
```

See the [NSString class reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html) for more information.