# Xcode line break in variable value

Tags: line-breaks

Is there any possibility in Xcode to break value into multiple code lines?

Let's say we have variable defined as follows:

```
uint16_t bits = 0b0111101101101111;
```

but I'm looking for something like that:

```
uint16_t bits = 0b0
                111
                101
                101
                101
                111;
```

Comment: does this help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16263720/split-nsstring-given-a-number-of-characters-in-objective-c

Comment: Thx, but absolutely it's not that case. It has nothing to do with strings. This is the editor matter or something.

Answer (score 0):

I've got an answer on Apple dev forum.
It's not directly possible due to C whitespace specs.
NSString category converting string into number (string can be broken using backslash) could do the business but it's to clunky for my purpose.